# Adding dynamically textviews to RecyclerView ViewHolder mess up the views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewholder

Im trying to implement dynamically textview, into my view holder, on the first scroll everything goes well, the cards and so are the properties for each, but if if i scroll back up again the textview start to pop where they shouldn't.

my custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(MyProduct product);
}

int counter = 0;
private OnItemClickListener listener;
private Context context;
List<MyProduct> myProducts;


public CustomAdapter(OnItemClickListener listener, List<MyProduct> myProducts, Context context)
{
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
    this.myProducts = myProducts;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if( myProducts != null) {

        holder.bind(myProducts.get(position), listener);
        counter++;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myProducts.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //Views
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewProductTitle;
    public TextView textViewProductDescription;
    public TextView textViewProductSerialNumber;
    public TextView textViewProductPrice;
    List<TextView> textViews;
    ViewGroup viewGroup;


    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        viewGroup = (ViewGroup)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearCatalog);
        textViews = new LinkedList<>();
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        textViewProductTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductTitle);
        textViewProductDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductDescription);
        textViewProductSerialNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductSerialNumber);
        textViewProductPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductPrice);

    }

    public void bind(final MyProduct item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {



        Glide.with(context).load(item.getProductImage())
        /*.asBitmap().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888).*/
        .crossFade()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(imageView);
        textViewProductTitle.setText(item.getProductTitle());
        textViewProductDescription.setText(item.getProductDescription());
        textViewProductSerialNumber.setText(item.getProductSn());
        textViewProductPrice.setText(item.getProductPrice());

        if(counter< myProducts.size())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.getBranchCounter(); i++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setText(item.getAddressList().get(i));
                textViews.add(textView);
                viewGroup.addView(textView);
            }
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any advice would be helpful, ty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding views dynamically into a recycler view is a BAD idea.  THe point of a recycler view is it recycles the same view structure over multiple items.  So when it recycles, you've suddenly added that view to a new item that doesn't need it.  Not having dynamic views is almost a pre-requisite of having a recycler view.

A better way is to play with visibilities.  Put the text view in all views, but make it GONE.  In your bind, you'd then set the visibility of the text view for every item-  either to GONE or VISIBLE.  THis will get you the effect you want.

Another way would be by using different view types for with and without the extra view, but that tends to be more complicated.

Comment: Ok i saw the trick with GONE and VISIBLE, but those are if u know how many textview u need, i may need from 1-5 depends the item. switch() ?

Comment: Then you're going to have some pain.  But I still wouldn't recommend dynamically adding the textviews-  you're better off playing with the visibilities of all 5, or of using different view types.  The alternative would be dynamically removing and adding in bind, which would cost some of the efficiencies of recycler view and be a pain in the ass to code.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @Gabe Sechan. But even if you are interested in adding textView dynamically. Then you can declare an integer at the top of adapter class like

```
int repeat=0;
```

Now use variable to count each textviews you have added. Also check whether it exceeds the size of your array.

```
if (repeat <= yourArray.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.size(); i++) {
        repeat++;
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        valueTV.setText(yourArray[i]);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearlayout.addView(valueTV);
     }
}
```

This will limit the duplication of the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Add linear layout, inside linear layout add dynamic textview then, above loop add below code,

```
 if (ll_layout.getChildCount() > 0)
 {
 ll_layout.removeAllViews();
 }
```

we solved our issue adding this code